# GPG error "repository is not signed" when I run sudo apt-get update

Tags: apt, package-management, updates

I'm new to Ubuntu and having some trouble after installing Atom. First time I failed and removed it. Second time I succeeded and got it running.

But now when I run `sudo apt-get update`
I get the following error:

```
W: GPG error: https://packagecloud.io/AtomEditor/atom/any any InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 4C6E74D6C0A35108 
W: The repository 'https://packagecloud.io/AtomEditor/atom/any any InRelease' is not signed.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: check his manual page, he seems to describe what you want to know: https://packagecloud.io/AtomEditor/atom/install#manual-deb - Quote: *In order to install a deb repo, first you need to install the GPG key that used to sign repository metadata. You do that using a utility called apt-key*

Answer (score 0):

Their are many another way to install atom.

1. You can download `atom.deb` file from the [official website](https://atom.io). and install it via `gdebi`.
2. It is available as snap. Follow [this reference](http://tipsonubuntu.com/2017/05/16/easily-install-atom-text-editor-ubuntu-16-04-higher/) to install `atom` as `snap`.

Source: [Github](https://github.com/snapcrafters/atom)